# Unable to fill in a ListBox in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

Hi I want to fill a list box with the items of an observable collection. I have in my XAML file:

```
<catel:UserControl x:Class="Musat.Classificator.CatelMVVM.Views.StopControlView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<catel:UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Something}" x:Key="cvsStops" />        
</catel:UserControl.Resources>

<catel:StackGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsStops}}" />
</catel:StackGrid>
```

and in my ViewModel I have:

```
 class StopViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   public StopViewModel()
    {
        ObservableCollection<String> Something = new ObservableCollection<String>();
        Something.Add("A");
        Something.Add("B");
        Something.Add("C");
        Something.Add("D");
        Something.Add("E");
        Something.Add("F");      
    }
}
```

However the list box is not filled with any data. Is there something that I am doing wrong because I can't find it?

Comment: Why do you bind through Static resource and not directly?

Comment: Another point, where do you set DataContext of catel:UserControl

Comment: I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Is Something a property? A DP? Does it implement INotiftyPropertyChanged? Please post complete code.

Comment: Something is the name of the Observable Collection

Comment: @user3182266 at the moment `Something` is local variable of the constructor and it needs to be public property of `StopViewModel` also  `DataContext` of `StopControlView` must be set accordingly

Comment: @user3182266 It should't be, but it looks ugly. Try to control if you have set DataContext correctly. You pasted only part of code. From this code is not possible to say what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are sort of guessing here, but could it be as simple as this? You must bind to either a property(with [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)) or a Dependency Property in a DO.

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> something = new ObservableCollection<String> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    public ObservableCollection<String> Something // Must be property or DP to be bound!
    {
        get { return something; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, something)) return;
            something = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Something");
        }
    }
```

Hard to do tell without your full code. How have you set your datacontext? Why are you not binding directly to this property?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Something}"/>
```

Check your debug output when starting the application.

Cheers

Stian

Comment: Well I'll be damned. I knew I was screwing something up just didn't knew I hat to make my collection a property sorry about that but again very much thank you :)